# Firebase database value keeps changing instead of adding itself

Tags: java, firebase, loops, firebase-realtime-database

What I want to do is to first check whether there's a value in my Firebase database, if there isn't then add it.

My database looks like this:

```
appnickname {
Strings {
    key : value
    key : value
    key : value
```

And my current code is this:

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot n : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (n.getValue().equals(string)) {
                    break;
                }

                reference.child("key").setValue(string);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

The problem with my current code is that it simply changes the string that exists under the same key instead of adding a new key/value combo. The good thing is that if it's the same value, nothing happens as far as I can see. How can I fix the bad thing?

Comment: does your database contain same node name ? I mean all there names are `"key"`?

Comment: Not exactly "key", but since for my app it doesn't matter what the name of the key is, but only value. I thought of just making it the same?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database is like this:

People

```
    name  : Peter
    age   : 100
    height: 500
```

Then you can do this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Peter").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
              //do something
          }
          else
          {
              reference.child("familyName").setValue(familyName);
          }
        }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

This will check if name equal "Peter" is in the database , if it is then do whatever is needed. If it is not add another key.

Comment: My database is not exactly like that. Using you example, hopefully it should be like this: People{   person : Peter,     person : Michael,     person : Jacob .....

Comment: its bettter not to make it the same "key", to be easier when retrieving values.

Comment: Now that I see, I cannot use the same key for multiple values. How should I only check the values and add new key/value pairs in?

Comment: its the same as I did in the answer, you can put the datasnapshot on the parent node and then use `orderByChild.equalTo` to do a query. Then using `exists()` it will check if the key/pair is there and you can add another one

Comment: I've tried using your code, but it doesn't work. I think because you're probably thinking that the key/value pairs that I'm supposed to compare are in a different child. They are in the same one. So when I compare them and see that there isn't an equal, it simply replaces the one that has the same key with a different value.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is you are using the key:value structure and sending the new value each time to the same key and that's also why when you enter the if nothing happens.

I would say give each one a different key but if you're using the same key for everyone why even use a key? just make a parent named people and put all your values in there.

```
appnickname {
  Strings {
    people {
      value
      value
      value
```

And if "Strings" doesn't have more children and your key was gonna be only people through the whole way than just call it people and skip another unneeded parent.